# set outputsettings for cloned elements in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

With Jsoup, cloned elements don't have a owner Document, which makes me unable to set output settings for these elements, and that leads to some issues in my app. Try this:

```
package test;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div></div>");
        doc.outputSettings(new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
        Element e = doc.body();
        Element copy = e.clone();
        System.out.println(e.outerHtml());//returns html not pretty printed
        System.out.println(copy.outerHtml());//returns html pretty printed
        System.out.println(copy.ownerDocument());//returns null
    }
}
```

The issue is that, for inline elements, this makes a difference. for instance, if I get

```
<body>
 <div style="display:inline;">
  test
 </div>
 <div style="display:inline;">
  test
 </div>
</body>
```

instead of

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">test</div><div style="display:inline-block;">test</div>
```

I get extra spaces, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I got the trick:

```
    Element elt = Jsoup.parse(elementToBeCloned).body().child(0);
    elt.ownedDocument().outputSettings(elementToBeCloned.ownedDocument().outputSettings().clone());
```

The idea is to make a new parsing to generate a new Document, and then clone the OutputSettings. No idea why I didn't think about it.

Comment: What is elementToBeCloned? Certainly not an Element that you want to clone because no method in the Jsoup class accepts Element.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here like me, I'd like to provide the solution I ended up with. As stated in the question, cloned Elements don't have an owning Document which is required to change the output settings. But printing the HTML of an Element without owning Document will create and throw away a Document anyway, so this solution shouldn't be much overhead.

```
Element elementClone = element.shallowClone(); // or .clone()

Document document = new Document("");
document.body().appendChild(elementClone);
document.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);

System.out.println(elementClone.outerHtml());
```